# itunes connect sessions metric

Tags: ios, testflight

I have an app in test flight and I just looked at the data itunes connect provides for external testers

"Expires in 47 days
14 Installations 
**1072 Sessions** 
4 Crashes"

My question/concern is what is a "session"? Should I have so many sessions with only 14 installs?

Answer (score 6):

According to Apple a session is:

The number of times the app has been used for at least two seconds. If the app is in the background and is later used again, that counts as another session. Totals are based on app users who agree to share their data with you.

If you have more questions about these metrics, google about "iTunes Connect   App Analytics Guide".